# How to do sum of array item's value until not reached at specified value?

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I want to do sum of array item's value until not reached at specified value.

Let me explain in details.

I want `20 k.g` value in each box , So following is my array.

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [product_id] => 2
            [customer_id] => 1820
            [order_id] => M-AAH-959
            [quantity] => 5
            [weight] => 1.3
            [cubic] => 0.00267
            [total_weight] => 6.5
            [total_cubic] => 0.00267
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [product_id] => 3
            [customer_id] => 1820
            [order_id] => M-AAH-959
            [quantity] => 6
            [weight] => 1.5
            [cubic] => 0.00348
            [total_weight] => 9
            [total_cubic] => 0.00348
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [product_id] => 8
            [customer_id] => 1820
            [order_id] => M-AAH-959
            [quantity] => 7
            [weight] => 1.5
            [cubic] => 0.00267
            [total_weight] => 10.5
            [total_cubic] => 0.00267
        )

)
```

You can see in above array there are 3 fields `quantity,weight & total_weight`.

So during loop i want to set `20` value to single box from sum of each items weight. we can take  quantity & weight from any three items for set 20 value for each.

So output will be..

```
Array (

     [0] => Array('box_item'=>20)
     [1] => Array('box_item'=>6)

)
```

Let me explain output array..

You can see total_weigh of First array `6.5` & second `9` & third `10.5`

I want to set `20` value per box, So calculation will be

6.5 + 9 =  15.5 , then add `4.5` from third array like `1.5*3` = `4.5`

So first box is for `20` & remain weight value is `6` so it'll be set is for second box.

**Note:** Currently i  have taken only 3 items for example purpose but there will be more items here and I have to set 20 k.g value for each for from weight of items value.

I have used following code but not helpful. This code is not given proper output

```
// First calculate the total
foreach ($main as $key => $package) {
    $packageInfo[$key]['total_weight'] = $package['quantity'] * $package['weight'];

}

// Then check count the packages ?
    $packages = [];
    $packageTotalWeight = 0;
    $packageItemWeight = 0;
    $cubicTotal = 0;

    foreach ($packageInfo as $key => $package) {
        if(($packageTotalWeight + $package['total_weight']) > 20){
            $packages[]['final_total'] = $packageTotalWeight;
            $packageTotalWeight = $package['total_weight'];       
        } else {            
            $packageTotalWeight += $package['total_weight'];            
        }

    }
```

Comment: If you don't need to know which part goes in where and just split it into 20kg lots.  Just add up all of the total weights and then split that by 20's.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bin_packing_problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This function will "pack" the boxes for you, selecting from each product in turn until a box reaches the maximum box weight, then starting a new one:

```
function pack_boxes($products, $box_weight) {
    $boxes = array();
    $this_box_weight = 0;
    $box_number = 0;
    foreach ($products as $product) {
        // will all this product fit?
        if ($product['total_weight'] < $box_weight - $this_box_weight) {
            // yes - add this product to the box
            $boxes[$box_number][] = $product;
            $this_box_weight += $product['total_weight'];
            $boxes[$box_number]['box_weight'] = $this_box_weight;
        }
        else {
            // no - add the part that will fit to this box
            $num_products = floor(($box_weight - $this_box_weight) / $product['weight']);
            $balance = $product['quantity'] - $num_products;
            $product['quantity'] = $num_products;
            $product['total_weight'] = $num_products * $product['weight'];
            $boxes[$box_number][] = $product;
            $boxes[$box_number]['box_weight'] = $this_box_weight + $num_products * $product['weight'];
            // add the balance to a new box
            $box_number++;
            $product['quantity'] = $balance;
            $this_box_weight = $product['total_weight'] = $balance * $product['weight'];
            $boxes[$box_number][] = $product;
            $boxes[$box_number]['box_weight'] = $this_box_weight;
        }
    }
    return $boxes;
}
```

The total weight in each box is available in `$boxes[*]['box_weight']`.

Sample usage (12 is maximum weight per box) to get the box weights per box:

```
$boxes = pack_boxes($products, 12);
print_r(array_column($boxes, 'box_weight'));
```

Output (box weights only):

```
Array
(
    [0] => 11
    [1] => 12
    [2] => 3
)
```

Or the full data result:

```
print_r($boxes);
```

Output

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [product_id] => 2
                    [customer_id] => 1820
                    [order_id] => M-AAH-959
                    [quantity] => 5
                    [weight] => 1.3
                    [cubic] => 0.00267
                    [total_weight] => 6.5
                    [total_cubic] => 0.00267
                )    
            [box_weight] => 11
            [1] => Array
                (
                    [product_id] => 3
                    [customer_id] => 1820
                    [order_id] => M-AAH-959
                    [quantity] => 3
                    [weight] => 1.5
                    [cubic] => 0.00348
                    [total_weight] => 4.5
                    [total_cubic] => 0.00348
                )    
        )    
    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [product_id] => 3
                    [customer_id] => 1820
                    [order_id] => M-AAH-959
                    [quantity] => 3
                    [weight] => 1.5
                    [cubic] => 0.00348
                    [total_weight] => 4.5
                    [total_cubic] => 0.00348
                )    
            [box_weight] => 12
            [1] => Array
                (
                    [product_id] => 8
                    [customer_id] => 1820
                    [order_id] => M-AAH-959
                    [quantity] => 5
                    [weight] => 1.5
                    [cubic] => 0.00267
                    [total_weight] => 7.5
                    [total_cubic] => 0.00267
                )    
        )    
    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [product_id] => 8
                    [customer_id] => 1820
                    [order_id] => M-AAH-959
                    [quantity] => 2
                    [weight] => 1.5
                    [cubic] => 0.00267
                    [total_weight] => 3
                    [total_cubic] => 0.00267
                )    
            [box_weight] => 3
        )    
)
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/uNorh)

Comment: But OP's desired another output and OP doesn't uses full info of each `$package` in resultant set. This is a solution of another task.

Comment: @AksenP yeah, it's probably a bit OTT. But the info OP wanted is available in the `box_weight` column of the output array i.e. `print_r(array_column($boxes, 'box_weight']));`

Answer (score 0):

You can get full sum and then pass each 20 to one element in resultant array:

```
$total_sum = array_sum(array_column($packageInfo,'total_weight'));

$boxes = ceil($total_sum/20);        // count of boxes

for($i=0;$i<$boxes;$i++){
    $res[$i]['box_item'] = ($total_sum - $i*20)>20 ? 20 : ($total_sum - $i*20);
}
```

**[Demo](https://3v4l.org/mZI37)**

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [box_item] => 20
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [box_item] => 6
        )

)
```