# I want sum of array specific array item's value until not reach at the end?

Tags: php, arrays

I want to do sum of array item's value until not reached at specified value.

Let me explain in details.

I want 20 k.g value in each box & total of cubic items that used in 20 k.g box , So following is my array

```
  Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [product_id] => 2
                    [customer_id] => 1820
                    [order_id] => M-AAH-959
                    [quantity] => 5
                    [weight] => 1.3
                    [cubic] => 0.00267
                    [total_weight] => 6.5
                    [total_cubic] => 0.00267
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [product_id] => 3
                    [customer_id] => 1820
                    [order_id] => M-AAH-959
                    [quantity] => 6
                    [weight] => 1.5
                    [cubic] => 0.00348
                    [total_weight] => 9
                    [total_cubic] => 0.00348
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [product_id] => 8
                    [customer_id] => 1820
                    [order_id] => M-AAH-959
                    [quantity] => 7
                    [weight] => 1.5
                    [cubic] => 0.00267
                    [total_weight] => 10.5
                    [total_cubic] => 0.00267
                )

            [3] => Array
                (
                    [product_id] => 9
                    [customer_id] => 1820
                    [order_id] => M-AAH-959
                    [quantity] => 9
                    [weight] => 1.9
                    [cubic] => 0.00348
                    [total_weight] => 17.1
                    [total_cubic] => 0.00348
                )

            [4] => Array
                (
                    [product_id] => 51
                    [customer_id] => 1820
                    [order_id] => M-AAH-959
                    [quantity] => 7
                    [weight] => 1.4
                    [cubic] => 0.00348
                    [total_weight] => 9.8
                    [total_cubic] => 0.00267
                )

            [5] => Array
                (
                    [product_id] => 144
                    [customer_id] => 1820
                    [order_id] => M-AAH-959
                    [quantity] => 8
                    [weight] => 2
                    [cubic] => 8.0E-5
                    [total_weight] => 16
                    [total_cubic] => 8.0E-5
                )

            [6] => Array
                (
                    [product_id] => 156
                    [customer_id] => 1820
                    [order_id] => M-AAH-959
                    [quantity] => 7
                    [weight] => 1.5
                    [cubic] => 0.00012
                    [total_weight] => 10.5
                    [total_cubic] => 0.00012
                )

        )

)
```

You can see in above array there are  fields quantity,weight, total_weight, total_cubic.

So during loop i want to set cubic total of that used in 20 k.g box.

Let me explain output array..

You can see total_weigh of First array 6.5 & second 9 & third 10.5

I have already set 20 value per box, calculation will be

6.5 + 9 = 15.5 , then add 4.5 from third array like 1.5*3 = 4.5

So first box is for 20 & remain weight value is 6 so it'll be set is for second box.

So now i want to sum cubic that used in box.

So cubic total for each box will be like .

1 ) K.G **20** `(6.5 + 9 = 15.5 , then add 4.5 from third array like 1.5*3 = 4.5)`

0.00267 + 0.00348 + 0.00267 = **0.00882**

2) K.G  **19.3** (6 (1.5 * 4) + 13.3 (1.9 * 7) = 19.3)`

0.00267 +  0.00348 = 0.00615

etc

Note:  there will be more items here and I have to set 20 k.g value for each for from weight of items value.

I have used following code but not helpful. This code is not given proper output

```
$main = array(

            array(

            array('product_id'=>2, 'customer_id'=>1820, 'order_id'=>'M-AAH-959', 'quantity'=>5, 'weight'=>1.3, 'cubic'=>0.00267, 'total_weight'=>6.5, 'total_cubic'=>0.00267),
            array('product_id'=>3, 'customer_id'=>1820, 'order_id'=>'M-AAH-959', 'quantity'=>6, 'weight'=>1.5, 'cubic'=>0.00348, 'total_weight'=>9, 'total_cubic'=>0.00348),
            array('product_id'=>8, 'customer_id'=>1820, 'order_id'=>'M-AAH-959', 'quantity'=>7, 'weight'=>1.5, 'cubic'=>0.00267, 'total_weight'=>10.5, 'total_cubic'=>0.00267),
            array('product_id'=>9, 'customer_id'=>1820, 'order_id'=>'M-AAH-959', 'quantity'=>9, 'weight'=>1.9, 'cubic'=>0.00348, 'total_weight'=>17.1 ,'total_cubic'=>0.00348),
            array('product_id'=>51, 'customer_id'=>1820, 'order_id'=>'M-AAH-959', 'quantity'=>7, 'weight'=>1.4, 'cubic'=>0.00348, 'total_weight'=>9.8 ,'total_cubic'=>0.00267),
            array('product_id'=>144, 'customer_id'=>1820, 'order_id'=>'M-AAH-959', 'quantity'=>8, 'weight'=>2, 'cubic'=>0.00008, 'total_weight'=>16 ,'total_cubic'=>0.00008),
            array('product_id'=>156, 'customer_id'=>1820, 'order_id'=>'M-AAH-959', 'quantity'=>7, 'weight'=>1.5, 'cubic'=>0.00012, 'total_weight'=>10.5 ,'total_cubic'=>0.00012)
        ),

       );
```

Script...

```
<?php 
foreach ($main as $key => $products) {
        $boxes = array();
        $this_box_weight = 0;
        $box_number = 0;

        $cubix = array();
        $current_cubic = 0;
        $the_quantity=0;
        $the_cubic=0;
        $i=0;
        $the_cubic_parent=0;
        $box_weight =20;
        $mainBox= array();
        $ttal_cub=0;
        $this_product =0;
        foreach ($products as $keys => $product) {
            $expCode='0000'.$i.'';                            
            $product_code = 'EXP';
            $startrackBarcode = "test";
            $ttal_cub +=$product['cubic'];
            if ($product['total_weight'] < $box_weight - $this_box_weight) {
                $boxes[$box_number][] = $product;
                $this_box_weight += $product['total_weight'];
                $the_quantity +=$product['quantity'];
                $the_cubic +=$product['cubic'];
                $boxes[$box_number]['box_weight'] = $this_box_weight;
                $boxes[$box_number][] = $product;
                $before_weight = $this_box_weight;
                $this_product += $product['product_id'];


                $ttal_cub= $ttal_cub - $product['cubic'];
                $num_products = floor(($box_weight - $this_box_weight) / $product['weight']); 
                $balance = $product['quantity'] - $num_products;           

                $boxes[$box_number]['box_weight'] = array('item_reference'=>$product['order_id'],'cubic_volume3'=> number_format($ttal_cub,5),'weight'=> number_format($before_weight,2),'packaging_type'=>'CTN','product_id'=>'EXP','authority_to_leave'=>(@$orders['authority_to_leave'] == 1) ? 'true' : 'false','tracking_details'=>array('article_id'=>$startrackBarcode,'consignment_id'=>"test",'barcode_id'=>$startrackBarcode));
            }else{

                $num_products = floor(($box_weight - $this_box_weight) / $product['weight']);            
                $balance = $product['quantity'] - $num_products;
                $product['quantity'] = $num_products;


                $product['total_weight'] = $num_products * $product['weight'];
                $product['total_weight_remain'] = $balance * $product['weight'];

                $num_products * $product['weight'];
                $product_cub = $product['cubic'];
                $boxes[$box_number][] = $product;

                $tes= $num_products + $the_quantity;

                $totalWeight =$this_box_weight + $num_products * $product['weight'];

                $this_product = $this_product;

                $tes_cub= $the_cubic - $product_cub;


                /*
                * This is for starting add data to array                
                */
                $boxes[$box_number]['box_weight'] = array('item_reference'=>$product['order_id'],'cubic_volume2'=> number_format($tes_cub,5),'weight'=> number_format($totalWeight,2),'packaging_type'=>'CTN','product_id'=>'EXP','authority_to_leave'=>(@$orders['authority_to_leave'] == 1) ? 'true' : 'false','tracking_details'=>array('article_id'=>$startrackBarcode,'consignment_id'=>"test",'barcode_id'=>$startrackBarcode));
                // add the balance to a new box
                $box_number++;
                $product['quantity'] = $balance;
                $this_box_weight =  $balance * $product['weight'];




                $boxes[$box_number][] = $product;
                $j=$i+1;
                $expCode='0000'.$j.'';
                $product_code = 'EXP';
                $startrackBarcode = "test";

                /*
                * This is for last iteme of array for add details of total weign and cubic              
                */
                $boxes[$box_number]['box_weight'] = array('item_reference'=>$product['order_id'],'cubic_volume22'=>number_format($product_cub,5),"weight"=>number_format($this_box_weight,2),'packaging_type'=>'CTN','product_id'=>'EXP' ,'authority_to_leave'=>(@$orders['authority_to_leave'] == 1) ? 'true' : 'false','tracking_details'=>array('article_id'=>$startrackBarcode,'consignment_id'=>"test",'barcode_id'=>$startrackBarcode));


                $mainBox[]=$boxes;

            }
            $i++;
        }   

       $itemArray[]=array_column($boxes, 'box_weight');

    }

echo "<pre>BOX";print_r($itemArray);
?>
```

Comment: @Nick, That was different question that already asked by me for calculate total. kg but now this question is different this is for calculate total of cubic that used in 20 k.g box.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to do sum of array item's value until not reached at specified value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59421440/how-to-do-sum-of-array-items-value-until-not-reached-at-specified-value)

Comment: @ManishVerma, No, That was different question that already asked by me for calculate total. kg but now this question is different this is for calculate total of cubic that used in 20 k.g box